# How to properly work with RxJS Observables when they needed as sync data

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx

Hopefully topic is more or less understandable.

I'm quite new to `RxJS` and `Redux` world. I'm working on Angular 2+ app with `Observables` and `NgRX store`.

In store I have different parts. Here what I need is to get properties from one slice and pass it to `downloadService` which accept `Array` of custom `AssetFile` objects with different properties.

```
  constructor(
    private store: Store<AppState>,
    private downloadService: DownloadService) {
    this.selectedAssets$=this.store.select('selectedAssets')
    this.selectedAssets$.subscribe(asset => this.assetsSelected = asset)
   }
```

Not sure if I did that part properly. In the UI once one Asset selected it dispatched to Store.selectedAssets. Here I assign it to this.selectedAssets$ and make another variable this.assetsSelected which suppose to be an Array of those selected objects.

Then I have this function to "prepare" files for download. Each Asset has property `assetFiles` which type is `File[]` in the end I need just `Array` of those files.

```
  prepareFilesToDownload(){
      let files = []
      let preparedFiles = this.assetsSelected.map(asset => {
      asset.assetFiles.map(file=>{
        files.push(file)
      })
    })
    return files
  }
```

This code works, but I believe it's not proper way of doing things like this. I've just lost a bit.

Probably I can achieve this result with less code and directly from this `Observable` `this.selectedAssets$=this.store.select('selectedAssets')`

UPDATE:

```
constructor(
    private store: Store<AppState>,
    private downloadService: DownloadService) {
    this.selectedAssets$=this.store.select('selectedAssets')
   }
```

Here I used `flatten` method from `Ramda` to combine array of array to single array.

```
  prepareFilesToDownload(){
    let files
    this.selectedAssets$.subscribe(
      assets => {
        files = R.flatten(assets.map(asset =>  asset.assetFiles.map(file => file)))
      }
    ).unsubscribe();
    return files
  }
```

Looks a bit better, but still not sure if it's proper way to work with Observables or not. I think better will be just return this array straight from `this.selectedAssets$` observable using RxJS operators. But can't find right way to do so.

One side question. Is it right to `.subscribe` and `.unsubscribe` as in second example or maybe I can use `.take(1)` instead?

Comment: I'm not familiar with NgRX, but .unsubscribe() is used to free up resources and avoid memory leaks.  It's typically called from ngOnDestroy() lifecyle hook. There is a good overview of Observable usage at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Answer (score 1):

I think your second option is much better and you were on the spot regarding removing the local variable and the subscribe. If I get it properly, once the user select "download" (or do some action with the files), you use the get files and the processing. In this case why not trigger the entire chain in one place?

```
this.selectedAssets$
  .map(this.prepareFiles)
  .do(this.downloadFiles) // or process files
  .take(1)
  .subscribe(); // you must do this to make the observable hot
```

This also relates to the `unsubscribe`. Not sure it works, and even if it does, it is less readable and standard than the `take(1)`.